# Twitter: How can I get all tweets in json format using twitter api

Tags: php, twitter

How can I get all tweets in json format using twitter api? I have already checked the process given in the link below:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

but got an error : {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Can any one suggest me what should I do. I don't want to use embedded timeline widget. I just want to show tweets from my account in my personal format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your authentication method - the API thinks that you are passing bad authentication data. I'm unsure how you are going about this, but this post explains a bit more about the issue you are experiencing:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11589

You should focus first on authenticating and making sure that is working before attempting to get the tweets. Feel free to clarify if you have any additional questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I have use sample code listed below :

```
$token = 'xxxxxx';
$token_secret = 'xxxxxx';
$consumer_key = 'xxxxxx';
$consumer_secret = 'xxxxxx';

$host = 'api.twitter.com';
$method = 'GET';
$path = '/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'; // api call path

$query = array( // query parameters
'screen_name' => 'twitterapi',
'count' => '10'
);

$oauth = array(
'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
'oauth_token' => $token,
'oauth_nonce' => (string)mt_rand(), // a stronger nonce is recommended
'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);

$oauth = array_map("rawurlencode", $oauth); // must be encoded before sorting
$query = array_map("rawurlencode", $query);

$arr = array_merge($oauth, $query); // combine the values THEN sort

asort($arr); // secondary sort (value)
ksort($arr); // primary sort (key)

// http_build_query automatically encodes, but our parameters
// are already encoded, and must be by this point, so we undo
// the encoding step
$querystring = urldecode(http_build_query($arr, '', '&'));

$url = "https://$host$path";

// mash everything together for the text to hash
$base_string = $method."&".rawurlencode($url)."&".rawurlencode($querystring);

// same with the key
$key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret)."&".rawurlencode($token_secret);

// generate the hash
$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true)));

// this time we're using a normal GET query, and we're only encoding the query params
// (without the oauth params)
$url .= "?".http_build_query($query);
$url=str_replace("&amp;","&",$url); //Patch by @Frewuill

$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $signature; // don't want to abandon all that work!
ksort($oauth); // probably not necessary, but twitter's demo does it

// also not necessary, but twitter's demo does this too
function add_quotes($str) { return '"'.$str.'"'; }
$oauth = array_map("add_quotes", $oauth);

// this is the full value of the Authorization line
$auth = "OAuth " . urldecode(http_build_query($oauth, '', ', '));

// if you're doing post, you need to skip the GET building above
// and instead supply query parameters to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: $auth"),
              //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
              CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

// do our business
$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);
```

and finally I got an array of resultset.